# Create a larger matrix in special case

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two vectors:

```
A=[1 2 3 4]
B=[3 5 3 5]
```

I want to find a matrix from these vectors like this:

you can suppose that `c` is a `plot matrix`, where the x-axis is `A` and `y-axis` is `B`:

```
c =
 0     4     0     4
 3     0     3     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0
```

or:

```
 c1=
 0     1     0     1
 1     0     1     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0
```

My question is how to create it automatically because I have large vectors.

Comment: Please explain the logic of how C is created from A and B?

Comment: Question is poorly written... Try making better explanation of your problem and you'll certainly get more help.

Comment: I added more details, hope that helps

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't. Do you want elements in a matrix in (x,y) = (1,3), (2,5), (3,3) and (4,5)? What dimension do you want that matrix to be? What is a plot matrix? If what you want to do is plot your x,y values:  `plot([1 2 3 4],[3 5 3 5])`

Comment: plot([1 2 3 4],[3 5 3 5]). yes, I want a matrix that shows the following plot, then it will be like c1:

 0     1     0     1
 1     0     1     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that `A` and `B` are coordinates, and you want to "draw" the plot in matrix form, so try this:

```
c = flipud(full(sparse(B, A, B)));
```

I added `flipud` to adjust the positive direction of the y-axis upwards.

Alternatively, you can obtain a binary matrix using this:

```
c1 = flipud(full(sparse(B, A, ones(size(A)))));
```

**Important:** for this solution to work, `A` and `B` *must* contain positive integer values. There is no sense in try to "plot" a matrix with non-positive or non-integer positions.

#### Example

```
A = 1:4; B = [3, 4, 3, 4];   
c = flipud(full(sparse(B, A, B)))
c1 = flipud(full(sparse(B, A, ones(size(A)))))
```

This results in:

```
c =
     0     4     0     4
     3     0     3     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0

c1 =
     0     1     0     1
     1     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: +1, for the reversal badge attempt =)

Comment: Hi, thanks so much. but I got this message:
??? Error using ==> sparse
Index into matrix must be an integer.

Comment: This means that matrix `A` or `B` contain non-integers values. How do you want to deal with non-integers? I suggest rounding them with `round` or `ceil`.

Comment: both matrixes are positive and integers like 3,4,3.

I did like that: abs(round(A)), but still same problem

??? Error using ==> sparse
Index into matrix must be positive.

Comment: @YSF No, this is not the same problem. This time MATLAB complains that either `A` or `B` are not positive (meaning that they contain zeroes). Since indices start from 1 (not from 0), I suggest that you add 1 to both inputs, that is: `abs(round(A)) + 1` and `abs(round(B)) + 1`.

Comment: you got my +1 for the attempt too! (and the question is on -5 now)